# Api call returning error **keyNotFound....**

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api, swift5

I am trying to make api call , I am building api in query and parsing it as usual , but I am getting error :

**keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "locationType", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "locationType", intValue: nil) ("locationType").", underlyingError: nil)** **)

Fetch data :

```
func fetchData(completionHandler: @escaping ([Root]) -> Void) {
    
    let queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "lat", value: "51.176519"),URLQueryItem(name: "lng", value: "-0.622557"),URLQueryItem(name: "date", value: "2020-11")]
    var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime")
    urlComponents?.queryItems = queryItems
    guard let combinedUrl = urlComponents?.url else {return}
    print(combinedUrl)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: combinedUrl,completionHandler : { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error with fetching accounts: \(error)")
            return
        }
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
              (200...400).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
            print("Error with the response , unexpected status code:\(response)")
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {return}
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let dataSummary = try decoder.decode([Root].self, from: data)
            completionHandler(dataSummary.self ?? [])
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

ViewController :

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    networking.fetchData{[weak self] (jsonValues) in
        self?.jsonValues = jsonValues ;print("JSON values Inside closure : \(jsonValues)")
    }
    print("JSON values outside closure: \(jsonValues)")
}
```

Root struct :

```
public struct Root: Codable {
public let category, location_Type: String
public let location: Location
public let context: String
public let outcomeStatus: OutcomeStatus
public let persistentId: String
public let id: Int
public let locationSubtype, month: String
public init(category: String, locationType: String, location: Location, context: String, outcomeStatus: OutcomeStatus, persistentId: String, id: Int, locationSubtype: String, month: String) {
    self.category = category
    self.locationType = locationType
    self.location = location
    self.context = context
    self.outcomeStatus = outcomeStatus
    self.persistentId = persistentId
    self.id = id
    self.locationSubtype = locationSubtype
    self.month = month
}
```

}

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Replace `print(jsonValues)` with `print("JSON Values Outside closure: :\(jsonValues)")`, and `self?.jsonValues = jsonValues` with `self?.jsonValues = jsonValues; print("JSON Values Inside closure: :\(self?.jsonValues)")`, see what's printed first?

Comment: Hey , thank for the comment , I have replaced what you have recommended . '''override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        networking.fetchData{[weak self] (jsonValues) in
            self?.jsonValues = jsonValues ;print("JSON values Inside closure : \(jsonValues)")
        }'''
        print("JSON values outside closure: \(jsonValues)")
    } only thing that it is printing is JSON outside the closure which is empty []

Comment: Now, do a proper `do{try}catch{}` instead of `try?` and print the errors. You are just ignoring the errors currently.

Comment: So I have added do catch block `do { let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let dataSummary = try decoder.decode([Root].self, from: data)
                completionHandler(dataSummary.self ?? [])
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }` and error is **The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.** not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Don't print localizedDescription, print just error.

Comment: **keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "locationType", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"locationType\", intValue: nil) (\"locationType\").", underlyingError: nil))**

Comment: Now we found the error. Would you mind edit your question with all these new infos? Also, could you share the code of `Root`, and add `print("String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")` to see your struct vs the json you have? The error is there, but we can't guess exactly.

Comment: @Larme I have found  the error , I had to make some values in **struct optional** as they where not properly handled and where coming back as **nil** thank you for the help , I would not found it without you!!!  you da best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was suggesting that it found nil in API response , as I did not took for account that the response can be **nil** I had made values in **Root struct optional**,then  it successfully parsed.

```
public let category, location_Type: String?
public let location: Location
public let context: String
public let outcomeStatus: OutcomeStatus?
public let persistentId: String?
public let id: Int
public let locationSubtype, month: String?
```